# Anchor: variable number of accounts in instruction wrapper

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

How can one set a variable number of input accounts for a an instruction wrapper?

i.e. given this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
   ...I'd like to specify here a random number of accounts
}
```

This is useful when you would want to refer to all creators of a digital asset (say NFT), but you don't know in advance how many there are.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I have just found out you can use something like this:

```
pub fn do_something(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> ProgramResult {
    let vec: Vec<AccountInfo> = ctx.remaining_accounts.into_vec();

    // do something with the accounts

    Ok(())
}
```